# How to use downloaded fonts in react?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am facing an issue with custom fonts. I have provided the custom font files (.ttf) in the public folder so that while building the app, all assets are part of the build. What should be the miss? I am not able to find it.
I have checked this [How can i fix @fontface issue in my react application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62329721/how-can-i-fix-fontface-issue-in-my-react-application) solution not working

```
    @font-face{
      font-family: 'FrutigerLTPro';
      src:url('./fonts/frutiger/FrutigerLTPro-Black.ttf')  format('truetype');
      font-weight: 300;
      font-style: normal;
      font-display: auto;
    }
   body {
      font-family: FrutigerLTPro,inherit auto;
    }
```

webpack:

```
{
   test: /\.(eot|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
   use: 'file-loader',
   include: [/fonts/]
},
```

Comment: Try adding `import 'typeface-FrutigerLTPro';` in root file i.e. index.js file

Comment: tried not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54860620/10295470

Answer (score 2):

No separate processor required

step 1 : import fonts in a css file

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Darkenstone';
  src: url('./Darkenstone.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Step 2:

use standard file loader in webpack

```
{ test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/, loader: 'file?name=src/css/[name].[ext]'}
```

Step 3:

Add the css file in root js file (like app.jsx index.jsx etc etc)

```
import '../assets/css/fonts.css'
```

Comment: What is the result? Can you share the error/output/challenge

Comment: there is no error just font doesn't applied

Comment: fonts loaded in browser ?

Comment: So basically the encoding is getting essed up due to webpack processing , please share the webpack , should be a simple fix